# How to toggle Wacom stylus pen in double monitor?

Tags: wacom

when you have double monitors, you have the option of mapping the stylus to one of the monitors or both. The problem with mapping it to both is that the tablet is distorted. When you write your text will be distorted.

So the solution is to be able to toggle between single and dual monitor modes easily.

Can it be done?